# Unicode characters in javax.swing only display when using the default font-size

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to display a few Unicode characters inside of a jLabel. Take for example, the "degrees Fahrenheit" character (℉ or "\u2109"). This character is only being displayed when I use the default font-size, which happens to be 11. When I change the font-size, the character is replaced with an empty square. I've tried several different sizes and several different [fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#List_of_Unicode_fonts) that supposedly support a wide range of unicode characters. Can anyone tell me why Swing only displays this unicode character under a specific font-size?

Proof:

[image: Proof]

All the code related to the UI is auto-generated by NetBeans using the designer, but here is how I'm supplying the text to the jLabel:

```
private void btnConvertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if(optToFarenheit.isSelected())
    {
        int tempFahr = (int)((Double.parseDouble(txtInput.getText()))
                * 1.8 + 32);
        lblResult.setText(tempFahr + " ℉");
        //lblResult.setText(tempFahr + " \u2109"); <-- Tried this too
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it will likely be impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: @JimGarrison updated my question. I see how it may clarify things, but the code is pretty trivial.

Comment: You have omitted the important part, which is where you "change the font size".

Comment: [Font support to U+2109](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2109/fontsupport.htm) is relatively limited and does not include e.g. Tahoma, which you mention in a comment.

Comment: Note that the DEGREES FAHRENHEIT character is *not* recommended. It has been included in Unicode only for compatibility with old character codes. A combination of DEGREE SIGN and a normal capital letter (°F) should be used instead. Ref.: Unicode standard, [ch. 15](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch15.pdf), p. 481.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "changing" the font, which might lead you to a font that is incompatible, try simply changing the label's "default" font's size

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestUnicodeFont {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestUnicodeFont();
    }

    public TestUnicodeFont() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            JLabel normal = new JLabel("Normal - ?");
            JLabel byCode = new JLabel("Normal code - \u2109");

            JLabel normalLarger = new JLabel("Large - ?");
            normalLarger.setFont(normalLarger.getFont().deriveFont(48f));
            JLabel byCodeLatger = new JLabel("Large code - \u2109");
            byCodeLatger.setFont(byCodeLatger.getFont().deriveFont(48f));

            add(normal, gbc);
            add(byCode, gbc);
            add(normalLarger, gbc);
            add(byCodeLatger, gbc);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the NetBeans designer prevents me from editing any of the auto-generated code. I'm sure I could find a way around this, but can you explain why `lblResult.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));` wouldn't do the same thing?

Comment: Why not use `lblResult.setFont(lblResult.getFont().deriveFont(24f))` after the `initComponents()` method?  Or simply, select the label in the form designer, find the "Font" property, open the font property editor and select "derive font"...

Comment: The only reason I would steer away from your first suggestion is to keep my code clear and concise. Although, it is only a single line of code, if I were to build on to this application in that manner, it would cause further problems later on, but that's just my perspective.

Comment: 1st - I would suggest you avoid the form designer until you have a firm understanding of how Swing, and in particular, the layout management API works; 2nd - I tend to use the form designer for a quick layout and arrangement tool, tending to hand code many of the finer details by hand.  The form designer doesn't have editors for every property :P

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I would prefer to avoid the form designer myself too, but I'm taking a UI course, and my instructor has made it a requirement to use the designer for a few of our assignments.

Answer (score 2):

When changing the font in Netbeans for you component, there is a checkbox in the font dialog "Derive the font from the default font", make sure it is selected and it should work.

Or you have to make sure the new font does support unicode characters. For example, "Arial Unicode MS" should work as well (it is mentioned on your wiki page)/

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem, using symbols in the text of a label in the NetBeans editor, by first produce the text with symbols in Word and simply copy that in the text field of the label.